# How to best transfer a project made in LAMP to WAMP without it breaking?

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, wamp, lamp

If i work with a php and mysql website (netbeans) in lamp and then when its done, export it to wamp. Will the project break? and if so, how do i best prevent this?

At work they use and base the system around windows, but i like to use linux (ubuntu)... i cant go against the system what to do?

Comment: no, project will not break. code never depend on wamp or xampp or lamp. only check the php version and mysql version if your code is compatible for a specific one

Comment: @urfusion, not entirely true, move project from Windows to Linux might break because Windows filesystem is case insensitive and Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: @invisal : true. but this is a pretty much normal if you are in this field. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing hard in doing that.

You need to take care the following things while moving your php code.

1. Extensions -  make sure that whatever extensions you have used in php are available in XAMPP also. For example if you have used php-mbstring in WAMP, make sure it is installed in XAMPP also.
2. Take the mysql dump using phpmyadmin , same you can import in XAMPP through phpmyadmin
3. Copy the php directory as it is to XAMPP and set the apache root accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Suyash said, make sure the versions (php & mysql mainly) match up.

I have once before transferred a project to be told it doesn't work only to find out the version of PHP was a much older version. Also watch for much newer versions if any functions are deprecated.